# What is a valid html for WithFooterTemplate method of PrintToPDF function in chromedp?

Tags: html, google-chrome, go, printing, chromedp

We have tried to add page numbers to our printed html page. But we didn't succeed. Right now the code looks like this.

```
chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            var err error
            buf, _, err = page.PrintToPDF().
                WithFooterTemplate("<span class=pageNumber></span>").
                WithDisplayHeaderFooter(true).
                Do(ctx)
            return err
        }),
```

Here is the source code of that method. Found it here https://github.com/chromedp/cdproto/blob/master/page/page.go#L812

```
// WithHeaderTemplate HTML template for the print header. Should be valid
// HTML markup with following classes used to inject printing values into them:
// - date: formatted print date - title: document title - url: document location
// - pageNumber: current page number - totalPages: total pages in the document
// For example, <span class=title></span> would generate span containing the
// title.
func (p PrintToPDFParams) WithHeaderTemplate(headerTemplate string) *PrintToPDFParams {
    p.HeaderTemplate = headerTemplate
    return &p
}
```

For some reason we couldn't find any valid html to inject here.
With that code the result looks this: there is a header, because I didn't provide a template for that, but the footer is empty even though I have provided a template to render page numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
buf, _, err = page.PrintToPDF().
                WithDisplayHeaderFooter(true).
                WithHeaderTemplate(`<span></span>`).
                WithFooterTemplate(`<span style="font-size: 10px"><span class="pageNumber"></span>/<span class="totalPages"></span></span>`).
                Do(ctx)
```

I don't understand why, but it works.